# How would I go about making a PowerShell Script into a Windows Service using the New-Service command?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services

So I want to make a new windows service using a Powershell script that I wrote, that when run executes the powershell script. Here's the command I want to run in order to make the service.

```
New-Service -Name "TestService" -StartupType Manual -BinaryPathName '"c:\path\to\powershell\powershell.exe -File C:\Scripts\PowerShellScript.ps1"'
```

When I run this command the service gets successfully created, but when I try this command:

`Start-Service -Name "TestService"`

I get an error stating Service cannot be started due to the following error:

```
Start-Service : Service 'TestService (TestService)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service TestService on
computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service -Name TestService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

**First :**

The reason why : A windows service EXE file is not a common EXE file, it contains specific entry points that are supposed to be called by the Service Control Manager (SCM) of Windows. PowerShell.exe do not contain such entries so it can't work in the way you are using it.

**Second :**

It exists a Microsoft tool named [SRVANY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/create-user-defined-service), or third party ones as [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/description) (Non-Sucking Service Manager) that allow you to encapsulate your code as a Windows Service. [Here](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-a-windows-service/) is an article that explain how to use NSSM with PowerShell.

Using NSSM with Powershell summary :

- Get the NSSM.EXE file (from the site, from chocolatey, rebuilding it from Git sources)
- Use the following code (to be tested) :

---

```
$PathNSSM = (Get-Command NSSM).Source # Path to NSSM.EXE
$PathPowerShell = (Get-Command Powershell).Source # Path to PowerShell.exe
$PathScript = "C:\PowerShell_Scripts\YourScript.ps1" # Path to Your script. Be carefull it a non ending script
$ServiceName = "YourServiceName"
# Arguments for PowerShell, with your script and no personnalised profile
$ServiceArguments = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "{0}"' -f $PathScript 
# NSSM usage : nssm.exe install <service_name> "<path_to_exe_to_encapsulate>" "<argument1 argument2>"
& $PathNSSM install $ServiceName $PathPowerShell $ServiceArguments
```

What I call a non ending script :

```
while($true) {
  #Your PS code
  Start-Sleep –Seconds 60
}
```